# How to commit and push to a private repo(A), from a different repo(B), in github actions workflow (B) , using personal access token

Tags: git, github, devops, github-actions

```
name: deploy-me
on: [push]
jobs:
  deploys-me:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: '14'
      - run: npm install
      - run: npm run dev

     //Next  I want to copy some file from this repo and commit to a different repo and push it
```

This is my workflow.yaml file,

After `npm run dev`, I want to be able to copy a file to another directory, commit and push to that another repo

Comment: You'll need some sort of "copy file" command, probably another "git clone" to make a repository into which you do this copying, a "git add" after you do the copying, a "git commit", and a "git push". Try writing the appropriate commands. If you then have specific questions about specific problems, *then* consider asking here on StackOverflow. As it is you've posted a question of the form "do my job for me".

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering :)
You are right i may not have been specific, I sort of thought of that copying and cloning again , but didnt knew if it was possible , i will try it, if possible please send link to resources where someone used git commands within workflow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
name: deploy-me
'on':
    - push
jobs:
    deploy-me:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
            - uses: actions/checkout@v2
            - uses: actions/setup-node@v2
              with:
                  node-version: '14'
              env:
                  ACCESS_TOKEN: '${{ secrets.ACCESS_TOKEN }}'
            - run: npm install
            - run: npm run build
            - run: |
                  cd lib
                  git config --global user.email "hi@aliasifkhan.com"
                  git config --global user.name "aliasifk"
                  git config --global credential.helper cache
                  git clone https://${{secrets.ACCESS_TOKEN}}@github.com/aliasifk/xxxxxx
                  cp index.js clonedFolder/ -f
                  cd clonedFolder
                  git add .
                  git commit -m "$(date)"
                  git push
```

This is how I fixed my problem,

1. I created a Personal Access Token from my `developer settings` and copied it for later step.
2. I added `ACCESS_TOKEN` environment variable by navigating to my repository settings and adding a secret. Here I pasted the previously created access token.
3. Then simply that code and using `secrets` context to access that token, note that name is similar to the one we created before

[image: In left menu of repo settings]

4. Now just push the code to repo and everything will work like charm :).

**Happy Hacking!**